# trigger event when youtube video is paused

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-javascript-api

I have text imposed over a YT video.

So far I am using `event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING` in order to trigger an event to hide a div when the video is started -but what I would like to also do is show it again when the video is paused:

What I have so far:

```
var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
        //height: '600',
        // width: '100%',
        videoId: 'lnzoWFylJ0k',
        events: {

            'onStateChange': function(event) {
                if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
                    hideIt();
                }

            }

        }
    });
}

function hideIt() {
    console.log("something happened");

    if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 767px)").matches) {

        $("h1.txt--white").hide();

    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an onStateChange event listener (Which you are using), and you could then hook into the "paused" state change.

You are already using the PLAYING event, is there an issue with using `YT.PlayerState.PAUSED`?

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Events

Comment: This seems like the logical answer, update the event handler to also check for that and showIt if it's pause.

Comment: doing this: won't work: -what I want to do is make BOTH events work  'onStateChange': function(event) {
                if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
                    hideIt();
                }
                if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PAUSED) {
                   showIt();
            }

Comment: namretiolnave "Won't work" as in "nothing happens at all"? Have you tried debugging it, seeing if your showIt method works? Easiest thing to do would be adding some print statements, lol. Maybe post your full, updated code?

Comment: Also you have a typo up there, maybe check your code for the same typo. (PAUSED not PLAUSED)

Comment: NO it works -my function was was miss named sorry and thank you!